# Will most solid state of something also be the coldest?

Tags: temperature, states-of-matter

It is said that when something is cold its molecules have low kinetic energy, how is that different from something in a solid state.

> ... The coldest theoretical temperature is absolute zero, at which the
>   thermal motion of atoms and molecules reaches its minimum –
>   classically, this would be a state of **motionlessness** ...
>
> Wikipedia: [Temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature)

If that is the case, the more solid an objects get, lesser temperature it should have making e.g. diamond the coldest object.

So my question is, what is the difference between being solid and having low temperature? Can we say that most solid state of something will also be the coldest?

Comment: "Cold" refers to temperature, "solid" refers to the phase, or the rigidity of the atomic/molecular lattice of an object in solid phase. I'm not sure what exactly your question is about that.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Downvote was well expected. What does it mean to have low temperature on molecular scale?

Comment: @LifeH2O Molecules have low kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2):

*Solid* and *cold* are two distinct concepts. As you can change the state (solid, liquid) with temperature (cold, warm), there must be a relation to it.

For each degree of freedom you have a thermal energy of $k_\mathrm B T/2$. Atoms in a crystal have a certain binding energy. If the thermal energy is way larger than the binding energy, no crystal can form. If the thermal energy is lower, a crystal can form. In between you will have phase transitions and the melting and solidifying of the material.

As the binding energy depends on the atoms and lattice geometry involved, the melting temperatures of the various elements are different.

Answer (score 1):

Molecules of solid object are still able to move and can even move in high speed if the object in high temperature .
Being solid only mean that those  molecules is hard to separate or make room ( like liquids does ) ,it doesn't mean those molecules have to be standing still .

That what I think . Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

Whether something is solid or not, generally depends on two things: the attractive forces between molecules/atoms and the temperature. The attractive forces will try to lock the molecules together and make it harder for the material to change shape (or being solid), but this can only happen when the molecules aren't moving fast. If they are moving too fast, the attractive forces will be overcome.

Imagine for example you are trying to walk a bunch of energetic dogs. If you have  proper leashes, the dogs can't run away, but if the leashes ae made of paper (weak attractive forces) the dogs can escape and the group can spread out and change shape.

Cooling something down will reduce the energy of the molecules until the point the material becomes solid. All material have a melting point (or solidifying point in this case), a certain temperature at which the molecules have so little energy they become a solid. This point is heavily dependent on the attractive forces between molecules. Helium for example has the lowest melting point of all elements: a mere 1 degree above absolute zero, because the forces between helium particles are very weak. Diamond has a very high melting point, because strong covalent bonds are keeping the carbon atoms together.

Comment: Can we say that most solid state of something will also be the coldest?